# Difference between view controller "use as launch screen" option and launch screen storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I noticed there is a `Use as Launch Screen` option under File Inspector for a View Controller located in the Main.Storyboard. What is the difference between enabling the View Controller as a launch screen using this method and using the LaunchScreen.Storyboard that XCode provides? Similar questions are about the differences between Main.Storyboard and LaunchScreen.Storyboard but doesn't specifically ask about the `Use as Launch Screen` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `LaunchScreen.storyboard` has this option **enabled by default**, but you can:

- create your own separate storyboard with an **initial view controller**,
- then select it as the launch screen for your app inside the project's settings (**Project settings/General/App Icons and Launch Images/Launch Screen file**),

...and it will also work in the same way.

[image: Launch Screen file option inside Project settings]

Xcode only puts the launch screen in a different storyboard to preserve an organized view structure.