# How to keep showing splash screen until Api is complete task?

Tags: ios

I Want to show splash screen until web-service response comes in the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between view controller "use as launch screen" option and launch screen storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555377/difference-between-view-controller-use-as-launch-screen-option-and-launch-scre)

Comment: consider the case where no connexion whatsoever is available for the device to reach Mr Server.

Answer (score 2):

`launchScreen.storyboard`'s VC stays a fixed time and directs to the `rootViewController` , You can create a view with the same look as the splash above the first VC's view and remove it when response come , that way you can fake the splash as it's still shown also it's better to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` above it / show network activity in statusBar to get a better UX

Answer (score 1):

The LaunchScreen.storyboard can't have any class associated with it. What you can do, and Apple suggests it, is to have the LaunchScreen have the same overall layout of your first View.

All you need to do is to have your web request be performed in you VC on Main.Storyboard, and have your Initial VC with the same UI as the LaunchScree.Storyboard.